# Creating Join-Table with indexes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, rails-migrations

When I want to create a join-table what I read from [rubyguides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) is that I can set the index directly as follows:

```
create_join_table :products, :suppliers do |t|
  t.index [:product_id, :supplier_id]
  t.index [:supplier_id, :product_id]
end
```

But when searching more on the topic I read I should add the index after the table is created:

```
add_index(:products_suppliers, [:product_id, :supplier_id], :unique => true)
```

Does Rails (4) understand the first approach or is it better to add the index after my table is created?

Would my two examples provide the same index or are they two different ones?

Comment: Try one way, `rake db:migrate`, examine `schema.rb`, then `rake db:rollback` and try the other way. Also, the first section of code you posted doesn't match the code in the link you provided.

Comment: In the 2nd example, you are adding a uniqueness constraint.  I don't think you can add the uniqueness constraint within the block in the first example (weird Rails quirk).  So:  if you want an index AND uniqueness, you must do it the 2nd way.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! That was what I was wondering about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as @Jason pointed out I tried both ways and it turns out it works just the same :)

```
create_join_table :products, :suppliers do |t|
    # either directly here
    t.index [:product_id, :supplier_id], :unique => true
end

# or afterwards, both work
add_index(:products_suppliers, [:product_id, :supplier_id], :unique => true)
```

even defining `uniqueness` works in the first example.